# How do we take a kubernetes cluster-info dump using the kubernetes API

Tags: go, kubernetes

Does kubernetes provide an API in its client library to get the cluster-info dump?
I went through its API [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#-strong-api-overview-strong-) and could find any API which could actually do this.

**What i do now:**

```
kubectl cluster-info dump --output-directory="dumpdir"
```

**What i want:**

Using client-go/kubernetes API libraries, make an API call to get this dump from a golang application. Is it possible?

**What i know:**

There are individual API's for each resource which can provide all the information provided by the cluster-info dump, but i want to do it will a single API call.

For example, this Golang code will give me a list of nodes:

```
coreClient := kubernetesapi.CoreV1()
nodeList, err := coreClient.Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})
```

Is there an API which returns what `kubectl cluster-info dump` would give, so that I can get all the details programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can capture API calls by listing the output with verbose option in `kubectl cluster-info` command:

`kubectl cluster-info dump -v 9`

For example:

> curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent:
>   kubectl/v1.12.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/4ed3216"
>   'https://10.142.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/events'

Get the token for authorization purpose in your cluster:

`MY_TOKEN="$(kubectl get secret <default-secret> -o jsonpath='{$.data.token}' | base64 -d)"`

Now you can make API call for the target resource:

```
curl -k -v -H "Authorization : Bearer $MY_TOKEN" https://10.142.0.3:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/events
```

Keep in mind that you may require role binding in order to grant view permission for your service account:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: default-view
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
```

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear. I actually need to do the kubectl cluster-info dump operation using the kubernetes api. i.e., i need the whole dump of the cluster by calling an API from my program instead of manually running the command "kubectl cluster-info dump"

Comment: I guess it's not feasible as Kubernetes API does not provide a direct API call to achieve this, about that @wilbeibi already mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Backup and restore cluster resources:**

https://medium.com/@marekbartik/kubernetes-in-production-snapshotting-cluster-state-41bd767ef14

Use ark for cluster backup and resotre:

```
ark schedule create <SCHEDULE NAME> --schedule "0 7 * * *"

ark restore create --from-backup <BACKUP-NAME>
```

Comment: I need to take a snapshot of the cluster at a certain time. I know i can get individual resources like config map using the API but is there an API which will give me all the resources which i would get when i manually do cluster-info dump using kubectl

Comment: @Bharath for that use case , you can use ark

Comment: Yes Heptio's Ark would provide a backup of the cluster but that would require a design change and we are not looking for any design change right now. Plus the information i need now is just for manual analysis which could probably develop into a new application for us. So i am looking at a program level solution for this, especially using the kubernetes library.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is no such API to do that. `kubectl cluster-info dump` is also implemented based on k8s sdk.

But you can refer the implementation and customize to your own needs.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/6fc89ae92d9d09bd70e74d32c6ba6b3d28e7bec7/pkg/kubectl/cmd/clusterinfo/clusterinfo_dump.go

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I have written a custom class for now which does something similar to this. This will definitely help me to refine it into a more cleaner solution.